# Get nested object values and put it on a table header

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, reduce

In the following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xxpgn-w95mpz) sample. I have the following data:

My table is displaying what I want, As you can see inside the timeline object the **"start"** values are exactly the same as the ones inside the **aval** array

Therefore, is there anyway I can display those table headers without the timeline object? (using filter, reduce or Array.from) Maybe I can loop to that very nested **aval** array and get them as an individual array kinda like

```
"aval" = ["11-19", "11-20", "11-21", "11-22"]
```

I'm using filter but getting nowhere so far.

**DATA:**

```
{
  "timeline": {
    "timeline_values": [{
        "tag": 0,
        "start": "11-19"
      },
      {
        "tag": 1,
        "start": "11-20"
      },
      {
        "tag": 2,
        "start": "11-21"
      },
      {
        "tag": 3,
        "start": "11-22"
      }
    ]
  },
  "employees": [{
      "EmployeeID": "56250f",
      "FirstName": "Downs",
      "aval": [{
          "start": "11-19",
          "end": "2",
          "ava": "30",
          "health": "4"
        },
        {
          "start": "11-20",
          "end": "2",
          "ava": "40",
          "health": "4"
        },
        {
          "start": "11-21",
          "end": "2",
          "ava": "50",
          "health": "4"
        },
        {
          "start": "11-22",
          "end": "2",
          "ava": "60",
          "health": "4"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Can you upload the full data and format it?

Comment: Is your question how to create an array called `headers` like `["11-19", "11-20", "11-21", "11-22"]` from the `employees.aval` array in the data you posted?

Comment: data is inside the grid.component.ts the variable is called **this.localObject** , please open the stackblitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you wanted the aval list from employee list, you can try a combination of `map` and `reduce`

- Map to create arrays of array which will have all start aval values for a particular employee `employee` -> `aval` -> `start`
- Reduce to flatten the array of arrays
- Finally use ES6 `Set` to pick unique values.

```js
const employees = [{
    "EmployeeID": "56250f",
    "FirstName": "Downs",
    "aval": [{
        "start": "11-19",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "30",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-20",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "40",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-21",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "50",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-22",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "60",
        "health": "4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EmployeeID": "56250f",
    "FirstName": "Mckenzie",
    "aval": [{
        "start": "11-19",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "1",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-20",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "2",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-21",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "3",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-22",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "4",
        "health": "4"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "EmployeeID": "56250f",
    "FirstName": "Charles",
    "aval": [{
        "start": "11-19",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "100",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-20",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "200",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-21",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "300",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-22",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "400",
        "health": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const mappedAvals = employees.map(emp => emp.aval.map(av => av.start));
console.log("************* MAPPED AVALS **************");
console.log(mappedAvals);
console.log("************* MAPPED AVALS **************");

const flattenedAvals = mappedAvals.reduce((acc, aval) => [...acc, ...aval], []);

console.log("************* FLATTENED AVALS **************");
console.log(flattenedAvals);
console.log("************* FLATTENED AVALS **************");

const distinctAvals = [...(new Set(flattenedAvals))];

console.log("************* DISTINCT AVALS **************");
console.log(distinctAvals);
console.log("************* DISTINCT AVALS **************");
```

Comment: Thanks. Reduce is not my forte. may I ask a good source of learning ?

Comment: Trying out multiple examples like adding a list of numbers, counting the occurrences of characters, merging lists etc will definitely get you started but sorry, I am not aware of any particular good sources. The way you use the accumulator argument is the key to reduce method IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (if it's supported) and a `Set`:

```
const aval = [...new Set(employees.flatMap(e => e.aval.map(a => a.start)))];
```

```js
const employees = [{
    "EmployeeID": "56250f",
    "FirstName": "Downs",
    "aval": [{
        "start": "11-19",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "30",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-20",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "40",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-21",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "50",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-22",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "60",
        "health": "4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EmployeeID": "56250f",
    "FirstName": "Mckenzie",
    "aval": [{
        "start": "11-19",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "1",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-20",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "2",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-21",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "3",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-22",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "4",
        "health": "4"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "EmployeeID": "56250f",
    "FirstName": "Charles",
    "aval": [{
        "start": "11-19",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "100",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-20",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "200",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-21",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "300",
        "health": "4"
      },
      {
        "start": "11-22",
        "end": "2",
        "ava": "400",
        "health": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const aval = [...new Set(employees.flatMap(e => e.aval.map(a => a.start)))];
console.log(aval);
```

Comment: This solution is much cleaner and it works , however there is a couple of things to consider. First, in Angular/ typescript, I have to change the data type of employees from any[] to any, which sometimes cannot be ideal. Also according to mdn IE and EDGE don't support it. they provide an alternative with reduce and concat tho.

Comment: @brohymn as for your second point about IE and Edge, the Typescript you write in your angular app is transpiled to Javascript that should work in all browsers: https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration